# TinyMCE jQuery validation issue

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I am using simple TinyMCE for my page. A problem occurred when I validate my text area  with jQuery.

jQuery didn't validate my text area.

1. Still save the empty text
2. Mentioned (".       Don't leave the Text area Empty") Error occued when write some thing in the TextArea.

**This is my code:**

```
<------------------------------------------------------->
jQuery code:
<------------------------------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frmeditpages").validate({
        rules: {
            txtdescription:
            {
                required:true
            }

                },
        messages: {
            txtdescription: ".       Don't leave the Text area Empty"

                  }
    });
});
</script>
<----------------------------------------------------------->
<!-- TinyMCE -->
<----------------------------------------------------------->

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-lib.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats
        style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->
```

Comment: please, provide the html code where FORM and TEXTAREA tags declared

Comment: And this problem occurs when tinyMCE is initiated? But not when you leave out tinyMCE?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware that tinymce is not equal the textarea! Tinymce will hide the textarea on intialization and create an iframe in which the user may edit content. Thus it is needed to call the tinymce save method in order to write the iframes content back to the textarea.

So you need the following code

```
var editor = tinymce.get( editor_id);
editor.save();  // writes content back to the textarea
// you may now use jQuery or editor.getContent(); to acces the content
```

Comment: Kindly confirm one thing please ; If i have two text ares in my form say A & B and want to implement tinyMCE on A only. is it possible?

Comment: yes, this is possible - the only thing you should make sure is that you only initialize the tinymce for the first textarea. You may do this using the tinymce init parameter mode described here:  http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:mode

Answer (score 0):

Defiantly work this logic

```
$("#buttontosave").click(function() {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var status;
    status = $("#menu_create").valid(); //Validate again
   /* if(status==true)
    { 
       //alert('true')
    }
    else 
    { 
         //  alert('false')

    }*/
```

});

buttontosave your submit button id 
note : plz validate hidden values also ,don't do like this

```
ignore: 'input[type="hidden"]',
```

plz put in to comment

```
   //ignore: 'input[type="hidden"]',
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me and same for you. Just place the following code before your validation calls but after submit is triggered

```
     var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); // get the content
     $('#textareaID').val(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

it happens because tinymce makes your textarea hidden. To fix the issue put this before the `validate` call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: []
    });

    // validate call
});
```